# Cypress: How can I wait until a pop up window would appear?

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I have 2 questions regarding pop-up windows that appear without a specified time:

1. When I open the website after some time a pop-up window would appears at the center of the page which includes a form I would like to test,
   How can I do cy.get() to the element without knowing when it will appear,
2. And when I perform other tests how can I wait asynchronously for the form element to appear in order to close it (it has a close button)

[image: Pop-up]

Comment: There should be trigger conditions for the pop up to appear. You should find out what those are so it's not a guessing game for you and your tests.

Comment: Waiting for a popup should be simple - just `cy.get(selector)` and increase timeout if needed. Haven't you already tried that? What problems happened?

Comment: But can I trigger the pop up to be visibile before its given time because it can take a minute or more until it shows up

Comment: And the other problem that I have is that I need to close it while I run other tests, because it fails my tests

Comment: Ah crucial information! Opening early - one way I know in Cypress is using `cy.clock()`, but I don't think that works here. @jjhelguero has the right idea - can you find any network request causing it? If so, you can use `cy.intercept()` to wait for response, then start the action of closing it.

Comment: I would ask one more thing - can you tell what type of popup? Perhaps post a screenshot?

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing the pop-up I'd like to handle